# ROS 2 DDS/Container Communication Issue

Tags: docker, communication, dds

I have an issue with communication between:

- Ubuntu 22.04 container running on a Ubuntu 20.04 PC
- Raspberry Pi running 22.04

Both are running Humble.

Essentially, communication works fine between both devices for a short period of time (couple minutes, haven't tested the exact duration). After then, only each device's local nodes, publishers, subscribers, action servers, etc. are visible. Notably, if a node is already latched to a topic on another device it will continue to receive messages. But if I stop and restart that node after a couple minutes of the container running (such as the demo_nodes_cpp listener) it will not long receive any messages.

I am currently using Cyclone DDS, although I was using Fast before and it showed the same behavior. The container was ran with the following flags: `-it -d --net=host --pid=host`

Here is everything I've tested:

- `ros2 multicast send/receive` (works both initially and later - never had any issues)
- `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker/listener` (only works if started in the first couple minutes)
- Various of my own nodes, action server/clients, etc. All only are able to latch onto topics/actions servers for the first couple minutes
- **Stopping and starting the container fixes the problem temporarily (I get another couple minutes...)**

Does anyone have any insight into how I could address this issue?